# C# dropdownlist change event

Tags: c#, events

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="myListDropDown" CssClass="text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListDropDown_Change" />
```

There's the aspx above

```
protected void myListDropDown_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //stuff that never gets hit
        }
```

I put a break point on the myListDropDown method but it never gets hit. Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `myListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged()`. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_events.aspx

Comment: @Rahul the name of the event handler does not matter.

Comment: @Rahul myListDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged() may make more sense but doesn't matter. Thank you for your participation though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property of your `DropDownList` control to `true`.

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="myListDropDown" 
                CssClass="text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListDropDown_Change" />
```

Comment: AutoPostBack="true" needs to be set to 'true',in case someone try to make it work without it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Autopostback property of the DropDownList needs to be set to 'true'.