# Asp.net How to hide a user control from a page based on the value selected in a dropdown box which is in another user control

Tags: .net

I have two user controls uc1 and uc2. These user controls are added to the default page. My issue is 
when i change an item in uc2.dropdownlist box to 2 then i need to make the uc1 user control visible else make the uc1 user control invisible. On load of the default page I was able to hide the uc1 user control by adding uc1.visible = false since the value selected in uc2.datagrid is not 2 on load. But when i change the value in uc2.dropdownlist box to 2 i am not able to show the user contol uc1. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Could you show some code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to postback when you do it, and you can manage the event in code behind to set visible to false.

You can set the uc2.dropdownlist to autoPostback, and use a update panel if you want to change this asynchronous.

Comment: @ Luis TellezHi Luis Thank you for the answer. I have set the UC2.dropdownlist to autopostback. And the UC1 is inside in update panel. Here is what i am doing. Under the page_load of default page I am checking to see if the dropdown box value is 2, if it is then i am saying UC1.visible = true else UC1.visible = false. When the page loads the first time it hides the UC1 but when i change the value to 2 in UC2.dropdownlist the UC1 does not show.

Comment: You are not loading the page, just part of it, manage the event of the UC2 changing, and there set the visibility.

Comment: check this other question on how to get the event. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415250/c-sharp-dropdownlist-change-event

Inside that method change the visivility

Comment: @ Luis Tellez I added the sub routine as explained in the link but I am not able to change the visible property of UC1 from UC2.

Comment: Here is the code I wrote in UC2 for the dropdownlist index changed event.<code>
Protected Sub ddlParentType_Other_Change(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  if ddlother.selectedvalue = 2 then
 'show uc1. I am not able to set the visible property of UC1 from UC2
else
 '
 hide uc1.
End Sub   </code>

And i am calling this sub when the dropdownlist index changes. It is my fist question posted in the forum so please bear with me.