# Dropdown list user click event handler not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to c sharp and I am working on a simple project but have found myself stuck.

I have a text field that just displays time and a few drop down lists that I want to change the color, background and font size of that time respectively. My code is configured below but nothing appears to happen on selection.

Any idea why my events are not being handled?

This is the cs code behind:

```
public partial class WebTime : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    } 


    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeLabel.BackColor = Color.FromName(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromName(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeLabel.Font.Size = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.DataValueField);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            timeLabel.BackColor = Color.FromName(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            timeLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromName(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            timeLabel.Font.Size = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.DataValueField);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the front-end asp:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebTime.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTime" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>&nbsp;Simple Web Form Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .timeStyle {
                color: #FFFF00;
                font-size: xx-large;
                background-color: #000000;
            }
            .listOption{
                margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <h1>Current time on the Web server:</h1>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="timeLabel" runat="server" CssClass="timeStyle"></asp:Label>
            </p>

        </div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="listOption">
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Black" Value="black" Selected="True" />
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="red" />
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="blue" />
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="green" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass ="listOption">
               <asp:ListItem Text="Yellow" Value="#FFFF00" Selected="True" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="#FF0000" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="#0000FF" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="#008000" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="listOption">
               <asp:ListItem Text="24" Value="24px" Selected="True" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="32" Value="32px" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="64" Value="64px" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="128" Value="128px" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. Short verion is `Autopostback = True` needs to be set for each dropdownlist.

More detail is better explained here as this question should be a duplicate

[C# dropdownlist change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415250/c-sharp-dropdownlist-change-event)